# Playframework: Custom template path

Tags: playframework-2.5, twirl

I was wondering if it is possible to override/add to the template paths for Playframework? For instance, the default templates are looked under views folder and are compiled automatically. These templates are further reachable directly using a URL without any additional config.

```
---app
   |-controllers
   |-models
   |-templates  //How do I compile templates under this folder?
   |-views
```

What I would like to know is if it is possible to add a custom path in addition to the `views` folder that is also compiled with the build process. Alternatively, is it possible to block certain templates to be not reachable by direct URL ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example for your point about templates not being "reachable by direct URL"?

Answer (score 1):

Under the `app` directory, Play should automatically compile anything that looks like a Twirl template - that is, has a registered extension such as `*.scala.html` - regardless of what directory it's in. The `views` directory is just a convention, and compiling templates under an `app/templates` directory should already happen.

If you open an SBT prompt you can verify this by running the command:

```
show twirlCompileTemplates::sourceDirectories
```

Which should give you something like:

```
[info] my-project/compile:twirlCompileTemplates::sourceDirectories
[info]  List(/home/me/my-project/app)
```

For adding a templates directory *outside* the `app` folder, you should be able to add something like the following in your `build.sbt` (for example, the directory `extra_templates`):

```
import play.twirl.sbt.Import.TwirlKeys._

sourceDirectories in (Compile, compileTemplates) += file("extra_templates")
```