# scala.html template file not compiled into object with apply() method (i.e. template.scala file)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, twirl

What enables a scala.html template file to be compiled into an object with an apply method (i.e. scala.template file)?

I added a new Play template to a newly created directory in my codebase. If I compile it, it does not create a scala.template file but rather an identical scala.html file within the target directory.

On the other hand, if I add the template to a different directory in my codebase - where there are other templates that already exist - and compile it, it creates an object with an apply method.

What is it that enables the latter directory to "work" and not the former?

Answer (score 1):

This stack overflow answer has detailed explanation for it: [Playframework: Custom template path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385904/playframework-custom-template-path)

To summarize:

1. If your template file resides under the app directory, does not
   matter whether it is under views directory or not. That template
   file will be picked up automatically for compilation.
2. But in your case, if the template file resides in a different directory. For example: the directory name is "extra_templates". In that case you will need to add following in your sbt file.

   import play.twirl.sbt.Import.TwirlKeys._

   sourceDirectories in (Compile, compileTemplates) += file("extra_templates")